# SQL query to identify mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare the same column for three rows for multiple accounts in the same table, how can I do that?

Example:  Let's take a table "account"

```
Accountno.     Name.    Date
01.               A.            01/03/2018
01.               B.            01/03/2018
01.               C             01/03/2018

02.               A.            01/05/2018
02.               B.            01/05/2018
02.               C             01/03/2018
```

My query should give output as account 02 because it's having a mismatch in the dates for rows A,B,C and should ignore account 01.

Basically, if there is a mismatch it should print the account, else ignore and proceed.

Comment: pls tag DBMS, the best answer can be different to MS-SQL, Oracle, MySql, Postgree, etc

Comment: What have you tried so far??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OP don't specified the DBMS below is a simple example using only subquery and aggregation.

To find the mismatch dates simple get max and minimal values by account number. So you can easily cut off that accounts with no date mismatches.

(Runs in T-SQL)

```
create table dbo.[Account]
(
    [Accountno] int not null,
    [Name] varchar(100) not null,
    [Date] date not null
)

GO

insert into dbo.[Account]
([Accountno], [Name], [Date])
values
 (01, 'A.',  '01/03/2018')
,(01, 'B.',  '01/03/2018')
,(01, 'C' ,  '01/03/2018')
,(02, 'A.',  '01/05/2018')
,(02, 'B.',  '01/05/2018')
,(02, 'C',   '01/03/2018')

GO

select x.Accountno
from
(
    select ac.Accountno, MAX(ac.Date) as lastDate, MIN(ac.Date) as firstDate
    from dbo.Account ac
    group by ac.Accountno
) as x
where x.firstDate != x.lastDate
```

**Edit**

The same query writen for **Oracle**.
Example on Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e96181/8

```
select x.Accountno
from
(
    select ac.Accountno, MAX(ac.MyDate) as lastDate, MIN(ac.MyDate) as firstDate
    from Account ac
    group by ac.Accountno
) x
where x.firstDate != x.lastDate
```

(Runs on Oracle 11g)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try it out and get back on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select ac.Accountno
from Account ac
group by ac.Accountno
having min(ac.date) <> max(ac.date);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: This won't work as required. See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a50cbf/5)

Comment: @cdaiga . . . Your "Demo" shows that it is doing *exactly* what you want -- returning account 02.  As stated in your question:  "My query should give output as account 02".

Comment: Yes, it does. The second row of data has `B2` and not `B.`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `exists` only:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.accountno = t.accountno and 
                    t1.Date <> t.Date
             );
```